# React Native Awesome Project Build Fail

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

Been trying to run the start up AwesomeProject file in VS Code but every time I run `npx react-native run-ios`...the build fail below comes up. Have looked through the stacks, comments, and questions here but I cannot find anything that is applicable.

Tried to change my terminal and Xcode to load with Rosetta but I get an error there too...

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
Installing Rosetta 2 on this system is not supported.

Not sure where to go from here... 

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/********/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-ekivgffrflagyugqmoefmykxoyqy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-337605CB7CDF90939BEBF863ED22C375.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this error too, i searched for hours...
What helped me was to downgrade version of react native to "react-native": "0.62.3" from 0.64

It also works with 0.63.

Others found this helpful: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32157